# On the use of elaborated type specifiers to avoid hiding by a setter function

Tags: c++, enums

The more I program, the more I like the [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) and the less the [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). There is one particular inconvenience irritating me a bit: I do not like getters start from the `get_` prefix, but that is not always possible without some extra work when using the snake_case. Consider, for instance, a getter for a member of `enum` type defined inside a `class`,

```
class bar
{
public:
    enum class foo { a, b };
    foo foo() const { return m_foo; }
    void set_foo(foo new_foo) { m_foo = new_foo; }
private:
    foo m_foo;
};
```

This won't compile since (if I understand correctly) enum `foo` is hidden in both the setter `new_foo` parameter type and the private `m_foo` member declaration by the prior `foo()` getter declaration. The obvious fix is to name the getter as `get_foo`, but as I said, I don't like it.

When I compile with Clang it suggests another "workaround":

```
error: must use 'enum' tag to refer to type 'foo' in this scope
    void set_foo(foo new_foo) { m_foo = new_foo; }
                 ^
                 enum
```

and the same for `m_foo` member. The following code indeed compiles fine

```
class bar
{
public:
    enum class foo { a, b };
    foo foo() const { return m_foo; }
    void set_foo(enum foo new_foo) { m_foo = new_foo; }
private:
    enum foo m_foo;
};
```

It looks like the [elaborated type specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) are even supposed to solve such kind of problems:

> Elaborated type specifiers may be used to refer to a
>   previously-declared class name (class, struct, or union) or to a
>   previously-declared enum name even if the name was hidden by a
>   non-type declaration.

But is not that a misuse of a language feature? Have you ever seen anything like that in libraries that use snake_case, such as, for instance, the Standard Library or Boost, or write it yourself?

Comment: I know that I does not answer your question, but your syntax seem to intend to 'hide' the get_ intention, then I wonder what you don't try to hide the set_ as well? Actually, you foo() could return a reference on the member, and then the set would be useless? Nevertheless, I don't think that would be a good idea, but makes me feel inconfortable with the 'getter' hide as I cannot get some consistency with the set.